# RWD Theme Category View Layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, rwd-theme

In RWD I have a 3 column layout for category pages - I want the category 'banner image' and title to show above the columns below - sitting below the breadcrumbs. How can I go about this? Here's an illustration of the current set up...

Breadcrumbs here...

Nav sidebar here   |    Banner and cat title Here & Products Below

Any advice please on how to get to the following....

Breadcrumbs here...

Banner and cat title here...

Nav sidebar here | Products here

[image: Page Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to create a structural block only for category pages. Steps to do this is given below.

### 1. Define your structural block

File : `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="category.top.banner" as="category_top_banner" template="custom/category/top_banner.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

Here `<catalog_category_view />` is a specific layout update handle node for category pages. ie Magento process this layout handle only when it renders a category page. Our structural block is `category.top.banner` and it is added to `root` block.

### 2. Call Our Block in Root Template

File : `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\template\page\3columns.phtml`

```
...
<div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_top_banner') ?>
..
```

As you can see, we are calling our block just below `breadcrumbs` block. Follow the same step in every page layout template files (ie files inside `page\` directory) in order to obtain the same result in every page layout.

Comment: Hi Rajeev, I've updated as you said above but the position of the image hasn't moved unfortunately, it's still contained within the wrapper.

Comment: @user2046646 I didn't get what you are mentioning as wrapper. but putting that line of code in different section of `3columns.phtml` will yield you different results. Try to put that just below `after_body_start` section

Comment: Hi Rajeev, thanks, but again this didn't have any effect, I don't think the code is actually showing the banner - the only banner that exists is the original which as far as I can see is part of the 'content' getChildHtml call in the category/view.phtml

Comment: @user2046646 if you done the above steps properly and cleared your cache, I am sure you are going to see the block in 100% width at top.

Comment: Do I need to disable (/*comment out*/) the existing call to the category banner image in the .view.phtml' file for this to work?

Comment: @user2046646 you need put that call in `3columns.phtml`in the right place. you dont need to keep the call in view.phtml file. If you put that code there it will not work as per my answer

Comment: Rajeev - I have the following XML file...<layout>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="category.top.banner" as="category_top_banner" template="custom/category/top_banner.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>

Comment: And here's the top of three column phtml...<div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_top_banner') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>

Comment: @user2046646 you need to define top_banner.phtml template file and and put your banner code in that file

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, is there a specific folder the top_banner.phtml needs to go? And what code content please?

Comment: @user2046646 location is `app/desingn/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/custom/category/top_banner.phtml`. the code that goes there is your banner codes which you have mentioned in your question

Comment: I now get this message Rajeev...fatal error: Call to a member function getImageUrl() on a non-object in /home/website/public_html/app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/custom/category/top_banner.phtml on line 5

Comment: @user2046646 this means everything works perfectly. Now it is your job to find why your banner code is not working inside `top_banner.phtml` file. As per your question, my answer helped you to setup a top-banner section in category page. :)

Comment: @user2046646 please accept my answer or put a new answer and accept it. I think this question is resolved.

Comment: Thanks Rajeeve, accepted and new question here if you do have any ideas..http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84820/cat-banner-call-results-in-fatal-error

Answer (score 0):

Goto theme folder `Catalog->category->view.phtml`

use this code Before

```
<?php
    $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    }
?>


<?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
    <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="page-title category-title">
    <?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>

<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>



<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Learning Magento - use this code before what please?

Comment: I've moved the image call to the top of the page (after the if statement) however it's still within the main column container and as such still sits to the right of the left hand navigation.

Comment: How you want exactly

Comment: Hi, I want the banner to be 100% width, as such it needs to sit outside the wrapper that contains the other elements. So you'd end up with banner on top, then the left sidebar and central column below it.

Comment: ..I've updated the post with an image of the desired layout.