# Cat banner call results in fatal error

Tags: magento-1.9, category, blocks, template, fatal-error

I have the following code in a custom block that is referenced in my three column layout. To get the category banner to show at the very top of each category page.

```
<?php
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$_imgHtml   = '';
if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
    $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
}
?>


<?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
<?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However I get a fatal call to object error, can anyone help? I've tried a simple echo hello to test there's nothing wrong with the block. So there's some issue with the code above. Thank you.

Here's the error..

> fatal error: Call to a member function getImageUrl() on a non-object
>   in
>   /home/website/public_html/app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/custom/ca‌​tegory/top_banner.phtml
>   on line 5

Comment: what is your block name?

Comment: category_top_banner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not using the right block class in this case. I am sure about this, because I know you are using `Mage_Core_Block_Template` block if you have followed [**my answer**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84392/3535) in your previous thread.

Let us look what is gone wrong here. The error says you are calling `getImageUrl()` on a non-object. This means `$_category` is a non-object. Now as per your template code, `$_category` is defined like this.

```
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
```

This means you are expecting `$_category` should hold the current category. But what really happened is it holds a `NULL` value since `$this->getCurrentCategory()` returns nothing. A quick solution for this is,

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($_category) {
    //then show your banner code.
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

Most of the case, it will work. If you template is more complex than this, then you may need to create a custom block for showing banner and then use that block instead of `Mage_Core_Block_Template` block.

Let me know your feedback after try this.

## EDIT

I tested below code and it works well for me.

```
<?php
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = Mage::registry('current_category');
$_imgHtml   = '';
if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
    $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
}
?>

<?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
<?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Works Rajeev, thanks very much. Could this block also now be referenced to show the banner on the product view page?

Comment: @user2046646 it only works in category page.